# How can I check the transportability of a RabbitMQ queue using the Java API into RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Sometimes, RabbitMQ might become unavailable or the queue you are trying to put messages into won't take the message for any reason.

I'm wondering if there is a way to check the 'transportability' of a RabbitMQ queue without having to actually attempt to put a real message in the queue and clutter it with potentially bad or useless messages.

Is there a trick I might be able to use in order to test that I can transport to a queue without actually transporting a message?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a channel to publish messages into the queue, if so, have you tried to check if the channel is open? with channel.isOpen()?, if you get a false, you can try to get another channel or implement a reconnection, I also use a scheduled task that runs every 5 seconds checking if the channel is open

Comment: This seems like a good idea. Yeah, I'm using a channel to publish messages into a queue.

Comment: Then I recommend you to do that! if the channel is closed when you check, try to get another channel from the connection, and if that fails, you will have to reconnect

Comment: Seems reasonable. I will try this out and mark this as the answer if that works for me. It seems very promising.